# How to call another screen after entering a phone number. android studio

Tags: android-studio

Can somebody help me. Im trying to create login screen. the first thing to do is to enter a phone number then after it will call another screen(if the number is not yet registered it will redirect to registration screen, else  it will redirect to password screen to enter his password.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
`EditText MobileNumber ;

MobileNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MobileNumber);

MobileNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            if(arg0.length()== 10)
            {              
              first check here the phone no is already registered or not

                if(phoneregistered==true){

                  Intent intent = new Intent(context, Password.class);
            startActivity(intent);

                  }
                else{
                      Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Registration.class);
            startActivity(intent1);

                     }

              }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method , just pass the number and your project's class name

```
public void redirectNextScreen(String phoneNumber){
 if(!phoneNumber.isEmpty()){
  // check number is registered
   if(isRegistered){
     Intent intent = new Intent(//your current activity.this, PasswordActivity.class);
     startActivity();
     finish();
   }
   else{ 
Intent intent = new Intent(//your current activity.this, RegisterationActivity.class);
     startActivity();
     finish();
     }
 }
}
```